# Counting generated random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

Alright, I'm supposed to create a program that generates 50 random numbers each between 0 to 49, and print out how many of each were generated. I keep getting 0.0 as a result, when I run the program, what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class randomArray{
   public static void main (String args[]){
      int min = 0;
      int max = 49;
      Random r = new Random();
      int i = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
      double[] numbers = new double[i];
      System.out.println(numbers[4]);
   }
}
```

Comment: You're not filling your `numbers` array ever.

Comment: You're just printing one number, the one at index 4. `double`s are intitialized to be `0.0` and you never change it.

Comment: Please use a proper title for your questions. If someone has a problem similar to yours they'll probably search about random number generation, not "making this work".

Comment: You didn't mention the intermittent Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/, specifically http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Up-voted question. At least he is showing code, showing that he's trying.

Comment: Jason, I note that your question isn't "what's the right way to do this", it's "what am I doing wrong".  Which is great - you're not asking others to write your code for you.  In my experience, the best way to find out what's going wrong in a program is to step through it with a debugger.  I think that would be an excellent approach for you to use here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to generate 50 numbers, then you should do this, usually inside of a for loop. I see you generating only one random number with your code.

Since this is homework, I'm going to give you general recommendations and not code:

- Create an array of 50 ints, say called `myIntArray`.
- Use a for loop, looping 50 times. Best to loop from `i = 0` to `i < myIntArray.length` rather than `i < 50`. This is important because if you ever change the size of your array, your for loop will automatically loop the correct number of times without you're having to change it.
- Inside the loop, get your random number, say called `randomNumber`, and print it out.
- Then use that randomNumber as an index to the array item and increment that value. i.e., `myIntArray[randomNumber]++`

Comment: And using that random number as the size of the array, which makes no sense.

Comment: Why use a HashMap instead of an array?

Comment: Probably have not hit upon `Hash`es yet in class. It can just be done with an array of `int`s. (Probably have not touched `Integer` wrappers either.)

Comment: @kviiri: You're right. A HashMap would be better if the possible numbers are larger, say a number from 1 to 20000 since it would be like a "sparse" array. Corrected.

Comment: Yeah, the array way is much simpler.  You don't need any logic around whether the key has already been inserted.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, yep, I was thinking I'd use a HashMap too if the range was fairly large. Upvoted for a good, concise answer!